# Laravel excel maatwebsite import, date column in excel cell returns as unknown format number. How to solve this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

how to solve date format?

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '43112'
```

My import class

```
 public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Agreement([
        'code' => $row[0],
        'start_date' => $row[1], 
        'end_date' =>$row[2],            
    ]);
}
```

Comment: what format $row[1] and  $row[2] has and what data type you have for start_date and end_date in database

Comment: my date format like 12-jan-2021

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` format is wrong, as the error says. It would be helpful to see what format you tried to use an input, but generally speaking the default format for `date` in mysql is `Y-m-d`, and for `datetime` it is `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Try changing your format to comply with either of stated two formats and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Convert date to mysql format using Carbon

```
return new Agreement([
        'code' => $row[0],
        'start_date' => Carbon::createFromFormat("d-M-Y",$row[1])->format("Y-m-d"), 
        'end_date' =>Carbon::createFromFormat("d-M-Y",$row[2])->format("Y-m-d"),            
    ]);
```

Also import Carbon

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

**Updated**
If it has null value in excel then

```
return new Agreement([
        'code' => $row[0],
        'start_date' =>!empty($row[1])?Carbon::createFromFormat("d-M-Y",$row[1])->format("Y-m-d"):null, 
        'end_date' =>!empty($row[2])?Carbon::createFromFormat("d-M-Y",$row[2])->format("Y-m-d"):null,            
    ]);
```

Comment: I try this i have this error `The separation symbol could not be found`

Comment: @EzatullahTabish is start_date and end_date are date type in db ? then it should work .is it null  value exist in any row  of  $row[1] and $row[2] ?

Comment: @EzatullahTabish if start and end date in excel are null then you can check null value .i have updated answer